# set a php variable to infinity when making a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that I want to make the following php/mysql query

```
$days=10;
'SELECT * from database WHERE days<$days'
```

which gives me the records that are less then 10 days old. And then I want to use the same lines of code but want to see all the records which is why I want to set the '$days' variable to infinity. But the code I have below doesn't work.

```
$days=INF;
'SELECT * from database WHERE days<$days'
```

Comment: Couldent you just make it a very high number? Eg. 999999

Comment: Think about using a different query to handle the _i want everything_ case, since it will be faster.

Comment: you can take a advantage, like your days never become negative, so the query will be `SELECT * from database WHERE days > -1`

Comment: if $days is infinity then you don't need where clause. use simple query (`SELECT * from table_name`)

Answer (score 1):

Just make `$days` a very large number: `$days = 9999999999999` There is no concept of infinity in variables or SQL.

Alternatively, if you just wanted all days, you could do something like this:

```
$days=10; //set days to 0 for infinity
$appendQuery = "";
if($days > 0) { $appendQuery = "WHERE days = " . $days; }

$sql = 'SELECT * from database' . $appendQuery;
```

Then, if you set `$days` to 0, the WHERE clause is not appended to the query. It's ugly but it's a work around to just setting a very high number and it's a faster query on a large record set.